# What is a suitable replacement for the mixer?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

The mixer is hard to automate. I tried replacing it with a LiquiCrafter, but that does not seem to generate sludge (only 1 output slot). What are my alternatives?

Comment: Are you using Tekkit Lite, rather than Tekkit Classic or Tekkit? Are you looking to specifically generate sludge, and for what purpose? Please elaborate on what you mean in your question.

Comment: Tekkit Lite, yes. I am looking for: automated crafting of mixer recipes, that will also give me sludge. And the reason for sludge should be obvious, i want to make it into clay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at the sludge produced by [MineFactory Reloaded](http://wiki.technicpack.net/MineFactory_Reloaded) machines, my personal experience is with a typical planter/fertiliser/harvester setup with a sludge boiler attached to the harvester; this was mostly automated apart from my power supply and balancing the production of industrial fertiliser to increase the rate of harvesting, or in your case of sludge production.

From the [FTB Wiki](http://ftbwiki.org/Sludge_Boiler):

> The Sludge Boiler will consume 1000mB of sludge to randomly produce
> one of the following items.
>
> - Dirt
> - Sand
> - 4 Clay
> - Soul Sand
> - Mycelium
> - Salt(Pam's HarvestCraft) - with Pam's HarvestCraft enabled.
> - Pile of Ashes - with Biomes O' Plenty enabled.
> - 4 Mud Ball - with Biomes O' Plenty enabled.
> - Hardened Sand - with Biomes O' Plenty enabled.
> - Dried Dirt - with Biomes O' Plenty enabled.
> - Hardened Dirt - with Biomes O' Plenty enabled.
> - Peat - with Forestry enabled.
> - Cracked Sand - with ExtrabiomesXL enabled.
> - Quicksand - with ExtrabiomesXL enabled.
> - Heat Sand - with Natura enabled.
> - Tainted Soil - with Natura enabled.